# Confusion in datasheet interpretation for TIP31

Tags: transistors, power-amplifier

The attached picture  is from data sheet of power amplifier TIP31 power amplifier:

[image: electrical characteristics table for TIP31 transistor]

Image source: [Farnell - Power Innovations TIP31 datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/4646.pdf)

Here VCE saturation is given as 1.2 V so for like output of +5V and -5V we should have Vcc of at least 6.2V to avoid saturation. But above there is written value of hfe or beta. At collector current of 1A value of beta or current gain is 25! But **what is the use of Vce here**? Like *what has this thing to do with saturation of transistor* or anything? Should our Vcc be Vo+ Vce saturation + Vce (at 1A current and beta=25). This thing is really confusing me. Will someone please clarify?

Comment: Feather - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material the source webpage or PDF etc. should be named & linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be the source PDF link for the copied image & added it. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks. (Please see the [tour] & [help].)

Comment: @SamGibson Thanku for adding that link ! I will be more careful from now on :)

Answer (score 2):

The current gain is specified at a Vce of 4V. As Vce decreases, the current gain also decreases.

Note that the Ib is specified as 0.375A with 3A Ic so the gain is less than 10 at this point they selected to guarantee the behavior in saturation.

I suggest you have a look at the typical curves and/or do some simulations to get a feel for the actual behavior. When you understand that, those numbers will make more sense and also may be useful in guaranteeing your design will work for any samples of TIP31.

Comment: So to have a stable gain of 25 Vce should not reach below 4V in any circumstances !Got it Thanku (:

Comment: Also Ic <= 1A. There is no maximum permissible gain so keep in mind it could be 50 or 100.